# Autofac - Inject properties into a asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have a base controller from which inherit all my controllers. This base controller has some properties I'd like to inject the using property injection.

My controller registration looks like this

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

I don't know how to access the base class and inject the properties.

Comment: It's better to use constructor injection, and only use property injection if you really need it. It's definitely possible with Autofac though (I have had to use it myself).  I don't have the code here, but will post later if no-one else has.

Comment: I use the contructor injection now,but there are 3 dependencies which must be passed to the base class and I don't like I have to repeat this in every controller I've created.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same scenario I faced.

Comment: @user256034 - How many controllers do you have, 20, 30?  Thats not a big deal.  Property Injection opens tons of scenarios where the state of components can change during runtime.  Thats really bad.

Comment: what do you mean with "tons of scenarios where the state of components ca" ? I thought properties are injected right after the class is contructed.

Comment: @user256034: right, but what I think he's getting at is that normally via constructor injection you are initialising a readonly private member, whereas properties are mutable and can be changed by accident.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();
```

Some more info on the autofac website: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/PropertyInjection

Comment: This helped a lot. It made me realise that by doing this you are setting the controllers to auto set **THE CONTROLLER** properties based on types you have registered. I was previously setting the `PropertiesAutowired` on the type I was trying to inject!

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider using an [Autofac Aggregate Service](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AggregateService):

> An aggregate service is useful when you need to treat a set of dependencies as one dependency. When a class depends on several constructor-injected services, or have several property-injected services, moving those services into a separate class yields a simpler API.
>
> An example is super- and subclasses where the superclass have one or more constructor-injected dependencies. The subclasses must usually inherit these dependencies, even though they might only be useful to the superclass. With an aggregate service, the superclass constructor parameters can be collapsed into one parameter, reducing the repetitiveness in subclasses. Another important side effect is that subclasses are now insulated against changes in the superclass dependencies, introducing a new dependency in the superclass means only changing the aggregate service definition.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Web;
using Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc;    

builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InjectActionInvoker();
```

Comment: 1) Have you registered the Interface/Concrete type with Autofac? 2) Is the property you are trying to inject into public?

Comment: Very strange. The types are registered (the are injected in the ctor) and also the porperties are public, but it still does not work.

Comment: The latest on how to wireup ActionFilter property injection can be found here: http://alexmg.com/post/2011/03/24/FilterAttribute-Property-Injection-in-Autofac-MVC-3-Integration.aspx

Comment: For me, I found a bug which prevents property injection.  It doesn't seem to work on global ActionFilters.

Answer (score 2):

nickvane's answer is correct. Just make sure

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();
```

is after your all dependencies are registered. Or in other words, just right before you build your container.

So final code will look like

```
.
.
.
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();           

var container = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to call also for MVC:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

For Web API:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```